# How to calculate sell price?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to sell something on eBay, but as you know they also take fees.

- eBay Fees: **10%**
- PayPal **0.19%**
- PayPal **0.35€**

Example: I want to make a profit (end price) of **16.18€** without fees.

I mean when you take the fees from that price ($x$) it should be **16.18€**.

I tried the following formula, but it doesn't work.

$$x - 0.019x - 0.35 - 0.1x = 16.18$$

Please help me.

Comment: Does PayPal take its cut at the same time Ebay does or is one applied after the other one has already reduced your profit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, up to a re-arrangement
$$
x - 0.019x - 0.35 -0.1x = 16.18
$$
lets collect terms
$$
x(1-0.019-0.1) -0.35 = 0.881x -0.35 = 16.18
$$
lets put similar terms together
$$
0.881x = 16.18 + 0.35 = 16.53
$$
now we need to get $x$ the price by itself so we need to do the opposite operation to multiplication, and this is division. 
$$
x = \dfrac{16.53}{0.881} = 18.762
$$
so the price you need to set is $18,77$ euros. (just to make sure you clear the rounding error to ensure the price you want)

This is assuming that we have linear deductions i.e. subtract $10$% for eBay, $0.19$% for PayPal and then the flat rate of $0.35$ all based on the original price, $x$.

Comment: Finally, thanks.

Comment: No problems! You did the hard part to be honest - modelling the problem in mathematics is normally the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal charges 2.9% + .30 transaction fee on each payment. You get the balance. That is their charge for processing the payment.

eBay charges 10% FVF (Final Value Fee) on the transaction: item price + shipping. The 10% FVF on item price is charged the minute the item sells.

If you want to calculate eBay fees (Selling fees) you can use some tools to get a predicted value, I would suggest you this tool: https://www.feescalc.com/